# How to create DevExpress report

Tags: winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

How to create a report using Devexpress (windows form)?

if possible i willing know step by step

Answer (score 5):

DevExpress provides a [step by step guide here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument9820).